# How to achieve @abstractstaticmethod and @abstractclassmethod in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to achieve @abstractstaticmethod and @abstractclassmethod in Python 2.7?

```
class Thing(object):
  __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

  # works
  @abstractmethod
  def instanceMethod(self):
    pass

  # how to do in Python2.7?
  @abstractclassmethod
  def classMethod(cls):
    pass

  # how to do in Python2.7?
  @abstractstaticmethod
  def staticMethod():
    pass

  # not works
  @classmethod
  @abstractmethod
  def classMethod2(cls):
    pass  

  # not works
  @staticmethod
  @abstractmethod
  def classMethod2(cls):
    pass
```

How to achieve Python2.7?

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the decorators, so `@abstractmethod` is on top?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'staticmethod' object has no attribute '__isabstractmethod__`

Comment: Order switch not works.

Comment: @BrenBarn Please specify duplicate if there is duplicate.

Comment: Looks that duplicate is for python 3.3 not 2.7.